# The effect of bouncing a liquid container

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, free-fall

I would first state that I am hardly familier with elementary Physics terminology, and due to not being a native English-Speaker, I can't recognize a question or subject adressing the next question of mine when I see one, as it is probably and legitimately worded differently with respect to terminology.

I used to open can of sode, or, generally, a container of drink in a bus, and noticed that whenever the driver passed a road bumper, as soon as the part of the bus I am in reaches the bumper, some of the liquid in the container would "fly out" (I was led to believe it is not flying out more thant it is remaining in the same spot not yet entirely influenced or something in that direction). This would happen when I froze my position and grasped the container. Very soon I would intuitively lift the container up after having reached the maximal height of the bumper, adjusting the lifting to the intensity of the bounce, and it would work perfectly. (I know the word "intensity" is too general and ignorent of the different variables that have to do with this physical occurence but I am really clueless here.)

Could you explain why those two phenomena occurs? Simplistically alongside terminologically?

I **do** welcome explanations relying on scientific terms, and would appreciate being referred to the terminology relating to the issue presented. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From habit and routine, you know when the bounce will happen and you raise your arm up at roughly same speed as the bounce, so for the liquid inside the can there is much less of  sudden movement. An [impulse](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impulse_(physics)) in other words, if you want to read more on Wikipedia

The bottom of the can is moved up at the same speed as the contents, so they will not spill, not as much anyway. You might also look up [inertia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inertia), as this is the resistance to change on any material body, in this case the change is a vertical acceleration,  such as the liquid in the can undergoes.

I bet some soda still comes out though, it's difficult to match speeds exactly.